# Send ASP.NET control value as a parameter using jQuery Ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webforms, asmx

I have a search form contains two ASPX controls, the first is a dropdownlist represents the "Medicine Category", and the other one is a textbox represent the medicine name. I've added a web-method to auto-complete the text in the textbox and it works fine but I want to return only medicines under the selected category from the dropdownlist (Send the selected value of the DropDownList) but I don't know how to send a value of ASPX control using jQuery Ajax

here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".tb").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../WebServices/MedicineList.asmx/FetchMedicineList",
                    data: "{ 'MedicineName': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item.NameEN
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1
        });         
    });
</script>
```

and here's the ASPX Controls

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_AllCategories" runat="server" CssClass="required"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and here's the Web-Method:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_MedicineName" class="tb" runat="server" MaxLength="255"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send the currently selected category to the web service (and modify your web service to get the category parameter, of course)nalong with the `MedicineName` you are already sending.
Select the current selected category using something like:

```
var category_value = $('#ddl_AllCategories').val()
```

and then filtering the medicine by category server side.

Comment: this is the way to do it. if it doesn't work you are probably doing something wrong but it's hard to tell without seeing all the code involved + debug informations.

Comment: what do you want me to post else to clarify the question?

Comment: you said you tried this method so it would be nice to look at the javascript and server side method you came up with